# Can we add features to geoserver layer using REST

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

As in ArcGIS Online, can we add the features to GeoServer layer though REST API?

If yes, can you tell me where i can find the help on this?

Or can you tell me how I can write my own REST API to Geoserver to add/Update the feature to Geoserver layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no REST based API for data manipulation, only for configuration. To modify vectors you should use WFS-T

Comment: Thank you.. can you guide if i need to create REST API for data manipulation what i have to do

Comment: I'm afraid a complete response would be a little book, if are good at Java/Spring you should look into the existing REST api and imitate the existing code: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/src/restconfig

Comment: I always wondered - if someone implemented the 'GeoServices REST Specification' to work with GeoServer, then ArcGIS clients could work GeoServer? (or Mapserver) http://www.esri.com/industries/landing-pages/geoservices/geoservices

Comment: One can only hope, given the is no official standard spec for it. But there is a good chance, ESRI needs to maintain its servers and clients compatibile with each other, don't think they can force people to upgrade both clients and server in a single shot...

Answer (score 1):

You should consult the online documentation for GeoServer, which has extensive information about the REST interface:

[GeoServer REST](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/)

There are also examples in a number of languages:

[Examples](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/index.html)

Comment: these are only for the configuring the Geoserver i think.. i need to add the features to layer.. Instead of using WFS-T